# iPhone application user registration and billing via apple ID account

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, app-store, in-app-billing

We are building an iPhone application for our project and I'm concerned that the **only** way for user to:

1. register an account;
2. buy extra content

Is via the user's Apple ID account. This is bad for us because:

1. We don't get user details data
2. 30% of sum goes to Apple

But as my colleagues say it's the only proper way to handle this - otherwise application can be banned from appstore. So could I have a registration/payment on website somehow be implemented inside the iPhone app? And in what way can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at how Evernote implement their service. You can subscribe to the Premium service from within the app via In-App Purchases, you could also do the same from their website, using credit cards or any other forms of online payment.

The key here is the user's email address. When the user signs up, they provide the service with their email address which is basically tied to as a username. I'm pretty sure you know what you can do next using the email address. Good luck!